# How is data passed from the Event Loop to the Callback

Tags: javascript

I'm studying Phillip Roberts [What the Heck is the Event Loop Anyway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) talk and generally understand the main concepts.

One part of the model I am missing is when a CB function is passed into the call stack (from the CB Queue) and the CB is invoked, how is the CB passed DATA or arguments?

Example:

1. I am making a `$.get()`, the XMLHttpRequest is part of the webAPI, when it is invoked on the call stack, the rest is processed in its own thread. Phillip Roberts puts this in a webAPI's category.
2. When it completes, the CB function is passed into the CB Queue.  From my understanding, the CB function still doesn't know or have access to the response of the XMLHttpRequest.
3. When the Call Stack is free, the CB Queue is checked and the CB from the XMLHttpRequest is added to the Call Stack.  The CB is passed the data from our XMLHttpRequest.  How is the Response/Data transferred into the Call stack?  How is the CB function passed the Response/Data?

Comment: It's an implementation detail of XMLHttpRequest and the JavaScript engine itself. 

The specifics depend on which particular engine is being used and can be entirely ignored by the JavaScript programmer.